# .net driving me crazy :) (64bit os developing on 32 bit HTTP 500)

Tags: iis, asp.net, .net

I just got a new machine, its 64 bit however I still have an application that was written in a 32 bit environment using .net 2.0.  I made some changes to the code and tried to debug and I get:

> ```
> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
> Calling LoadLibraryEx on ISAPI filter
> ```
>
> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_filter.dll"
>   failed"

So I googled for the life of me and it tells me to reregister IIS.
I do that several times but to no avail.  I also checked the app pool for this app and it was set to use the wrong .net version (4.0).  So I changed it to use 2.0.  Restarted IIS tried to run the app same error message.

If I go into IIS management right click the site name select "Manage Application"->"Advanced Settings..."  I have the screen shot here:

[image]

If I click on the application pool section it says this:

[image]

So I am not sure what I am doing wrong...I look inside c:\windows\microsoft.net and I have the 2 folders "Framework" and "Framework64" I assume the prior is for 32 bit:

[image]

Finally the last thing I look at is the "ISAPI and CGI Restrictions" within IIS Management.  Here is what they are set to:

[image]

Again I am running on an AMD64 bit system running windows 7.  I have all the various frameworks installed, however this particular app is an asp.net 2.0 application.  Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Why was this closed as off topic?  What is so off topic about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow I got it working thanks to this: http://www.codertakeout.com/v/35674/4O9BY
I had to enable 32 bit apps in the app pool as well as enable the ISAPI CGI Restrictions for the 32 bit version of ASP.net v2.0

All confusing stuff!